# Gunicorn throws ModuleNotFound for some (but not all) flask modules

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a basic flask app with this structure:

```
/
├── app.py
├── models.py
├── venv
│   ├── bin
│   └── ...
```

And `app.py` has these imports:

```
from flask import (
  Flask,
  g,
  render_template,
  flash,
  redirect,
  url_for,
  abort,
  jsonify
)
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_login import (
  LoginManager,
  login_user,
  logout_user,
  login_required,
  current_user
)
from flask_bcrypt import check_password_hash
from flask_expects_json import expects_json
from flask_jwt_extended import (
  JWTManager, 
  create_access_token, 
  create_refresh_token, 
  fresh_jwt_required,
  jwt_refresh_token_required, 
  get_jwt_identity, 
  get_raw_jwt
)
```

I'm trying to start the app with `gunicorn app:app`, but I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_bcrypt'` when I do.

All of the modules are in fact installed and I can run the app with `python3 app.py` just fine. If I move the `from flask_bcrypt...` line to the bottom, I get the same error for `flask_expects_json` and then `flask_jwt_extended`.

I don't understand why this is happening and I especially don't understand why `flask`, `flask_cors`, and `flask_login` *don't* give this error.

Any help is greatly appreciated; thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to activate my virtualenv

Thanks, no sleep! It actually works fine

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing `flask_bcrypt` as `from flask.ext.bcrypt import check_password_hash`

Comment: Thanks, but Flask extensions no longer use the `flask.ext` syntax, so this wouldn't help.